# How to plot the boundary of the corresponding convex cone in MATLAB

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

The special set of $n\times n$ real symmetric positive semidefinite matrices, denoted by + is called a convex cone. Consider the special case +2. For a symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix}$ the conditions $y^2>xz$ and $x+z \ge 0$ makes $A$ to positive semi-definite matrix. Plot the boundary of the corresponding convex cone, i.e., $y^2=xz$ where $x\ge 0$ and $z\ge 0$ in − in MATLAB. NOTE: You can use ([45 45 10]) command to adjust azimuth, elevation and skew of the plot, respectively. Does anybody know how can ı code this in MATLAB?

Comment: Most probably your condition is wrong, and it should be $y^2 < xz$, $x>0$, and $z>0$. Try to look for the surf Matlab command and its examples.

Comment: no ı check the question and ı didn't mistake

Comment: The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 &2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is not positive semidefinite, but it it fits your requriements (as far as I see).

Comment: okay lets change the conditions like you said, do you know the code then,can you help me

Comment: You should read the help for the surf command in matlab. And probably google a bit.